# How to find *where* in ActiveDirectory an attribute is stored?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powerquery

I want to use Power Query to extract a list of employee names including attributes such as username, telephone number, office number, etc.

I found an article that shows how to do just that:
http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/pull-your-global-address-book-into-excel/

However, my question is: if I wanted to return an attribute that I know that exists, but I haven't a clue where in the Active Directory object/table model it resides, how might one perform a search to find the *specific table & attribute* that must be queried?

**EDIT - Additional Information**
"Is this more of a PowerQuery question that a PowerShell question" - I think the answer is both yes and no.

This command:

```
Get-ADUser <someValidUserName> - Property *
```

...does indeed output *all* the attributes for the specified user.  However, as far as I can tell there is no indication in the output as to where in the AD object hierarchy each attribute resides.

From the Power Query article linked above, we see several "tables" noted in the Power Query interface to Active Directory.  One such table is `organizationalPerson` which contains an attribute named `physicalDeliveryOfficeName`.  It would seem that the notion of an `organizationalPerson` "object" isn't exclusive to Power Query, as it seems to correspond to the `Ldap-Display-Name` as documented here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683883(v=vs.85).aspx

So what I was hoping for was a means to wildcard search the AD attribute names themselves for the existence of the word "office" *anywhere within* any attribute name in the AD user hierarchy, and for the search results to return physicalDelivery**Office**Name as a result, including the fact that it resides within **organizationalPerson**

(Hopefully that makes the question a bit more clear?)

Comment: With the AD cmdlets: ***Get-ADUser FOO -Property **** Then look through the returned properties. Not sure what Power Query is or how to use it for the same thing.

Comment: Just to be sure the stars dont obfuscate what EBGreen is trying to show you `Get-ADUser FOO -Property *`. THat will return all properties of the object. You could even filter on the values and return the property name based on the value. There is no real tables that you would need to know about.

Comment: Is this more of a PowerQuery question that a PowerShell question?

Comment: Yeah, the stars were a poor attempt to get bold italic formatting for the code. Completely forgetting that the last character of the code was a star. :)

Comment: MSDN has [the schema for Active Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675085(v=vs.85).aspx).  It's a pain in the ass to search because just about everything has three or so names, but all the attributes are there and it gets easier once you figure out how to use the site.  You can also dig into the schema directly with [AD Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/adexplorer.aspx).  [SelfADSI](http://www.selfadsi.org/index.htm) also has some good documentation, as does the old [RL Mueller site](http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm).

Comment: @EBGreen Get-ADUser seems to get one close - I added some additional details to the question on the problem I'm still having.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity: Here is a `PowerShell` script (See Get Class Attributes) that will list all `Active Directory` `classes` + `class attributes` for a specified `SamAccountName`. From the list of attributes, you can then run something like the following to get the attribute values

```
#make a list of desired class attributes
$Properties = @('DisplayName', 'SamAccountName', 'mail', 'otherMailbox')
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=myDomain,dc=gov" -Properties $Properties |  select $Properties
```

**Credit to: http://virot.eu/getting-all-possible-classes-attributes-for-a-ad-object/**

**Get Class Attributes**

```
#Run on Win 7 machine with PS 4.0 against A.D. running on a Win 2008 R2 domain controller

cls

$attributeList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$attributeListItem = [ordered]@{} 

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Get an AD User and request objectClass
$aDObj = Get-ADUser "MyAccountName" -Properties objectClass

#get all class names 
$nextClass = $aDObj.ObjectClass

$allClasses = Do
{
    $currentClass = $nextClass
    $nextClass = Get-ADObject -SearchBase "$((Get-ADRootDSE).SchemaNamingContext)" -Filter {lDAPDisplayName -eq $nextClass} -properties subClassOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty subClassOf
    $currentClass
}
While($currentClass -ne $nextClass)

#Get all attributes
$mandatoryAndOptionalAttributes = 'MayContain','MustContain','systemMayContain','systemMustContain'

ForEach ($class in $allClasses)
{

    $classInfo = Get-ADObject -SearchBase "$((Get-ADRootDSE).SchemaNamingContext)" -Filter {lDAPDisplayName -eq $class} -properties $mandatoryAndOptionalAttributes 

    ForEach ($mandatoryAndOptionalAttribute in $mandatoryAndOptionalAttributes)
    {

        foreach ($classAttribute in $classInfo.$mandatoryAndOptionalAttribute)
        {
            $attributeListItem."Mandatory/Optional Attribute" = $mandatoryAndOptionalAttribute
            $attributeListItem."Class" = $classInfo.Name
            $attributeListItem."Class Attribute" = $classAttribute
            $attributeList.add((New-Object PSObject -Property $attributeListItem)) | out-null
        }
    }
}

$attributeList | out-gridview -title ("All Class Attributes: " + $attributeList.count)
```